# When .net office add-in targets Any CPU what determines the bitness, OS bitness or Office bitness?

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, 32bit-64bit

When a .NET office add-in targets 'Any CPU', what determines the bitness of the addin process--the bitness of Office or the bitness of the Windows O/S?

The reason I ask is because my addin needs to support 32-bit Office on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.  I do not need to support 64-bit Office.  Since I need to deploy my add-in with an .MSI, I was hoping to only have to create a single 32-bit .MSI which I (currently) believe will be sufficient as long as my add-in runs with the same bitness of Office and not Windows.

Comment: Just for the case, did you consider targeting add-in to x86?

Comment: Excellent question since that would probably tell me the answer, but I don't currently have a 64 bit workstation to test against

Comment: If you target add-in to x86 - it will run as 32-bit process.

Comment: An Office add-in runs in-process inside the Office process.  So the bitness of Office matters.  Don't advertize features you cannot test on your own machine.

Comment: The thing is, I actually want my addin to run as 64 bit on 64 bit Windows since an external SCCM script (I have no control of) running as 64bit on the same machine will write to registry, and due to registry redirection, my addin can only read those registry entries (without me having to modify code) if it also runs as 64bit.  So if my addin's bitness matches Windows, then it should work without code changes, but if my addin's bitness matches Office, then I'm forced to.

Comment: @hans you can go ahead and post and I'll mark as the answer